# SSAS DefaultMaxDrillThroughRows is set 10000 but showing 1000 only in sql server

Tags: ssas, olap-cube, drillthrough

When I am browsing the deployed cube in SSAS server, the drillthrough action is returning only the first 1000 records.

I have already checked the DefaultMaxDrillThroughRows value for the server and it is set as 10,000. Yet the records being returned are less than 10,000.

Is this happening because of server incapability or is there any way I can view all the records and not just the 1000 records?

Please note that I am viewing the cube directly from SSAS server and not through any other client software.

SSAS experts please help :)
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there is a 1000 row limit on that viewer in SSMS. Since I imagine no real end users will use SSMS for their client tool I would recommend you focus on Excel. There is a setting you need to pay attention to in Excel: http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2010/03/excel-cube-pivot-drillthrough-limited-to-1000-rows/

Comment: Hi @GregGalloway, actually I have a different client application called Dundas Dashboard for viewing this cube. Even through this client app, the total number of records being displayed is 1000 only and so I was checking if there was an issue within the SSAS server itself ...

Comment: In the cube designer have you defined a drillthrough action on the Actions tab? Under Additional Properties you can control the max rows.

Comment: Yeah I have already checked for that property as well :)

Comment: Can you run this in an MDX window in SSMS and see how many rows it returns? DRILLTHROUGH SELECT FROM [YourCube] WHERE ([Measures].[Your Measure])

Comment: The query is returning 10,000 rows! What does that mean?

Comment: I guess the other client tools must have a max rows setting of their own?